# Trying to push a new screen when a component is mounted using useEffect, however, I get that the 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was seeing a strange issue where if I pushed a screen using a button click, everything would go through just fine, however, if I tried doing the same using an useEffect it would not work.

Then I noticed the following error:

```
The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted, or if the navigator hasn't finished mounting. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization for more details.
```

And after following the documentation link, I realized that when I'm pushing the screen on component mount using the useEffect, the root navigation is not initialized yet which is why it fails. And it works on button click because at that point, the root navigation is initialized.

Now my question is how to avoid this issue while still pushing the screen on component mount using useEffect? I am making a GET request to a specific endpoint, and based on what that endpoint returns I either do nothing or push the new screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await shouldRedirect();
        result?.redirect && startActivity({ activitySlug: result.redirect });
    })();
}, [startActivity]);
```